# What does General Settings > Logo do?

Tags: control-panel, dashboard

I am a craft newbie and was wondering what General Settings > Logo does, as I can't find anything about it (how to use it with twig etc.) in the documentation or elsewhere.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo you upload there will replace the default Craft graphic on the login page for the Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

It lets you add a custom logo to your control panel.